# How do ensure sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture returns values?

Tags: sql-server-2017, cdc

I am trying to review some CDC setup information about a SQL Server 2017 database and I'm getting stuck because a specific query that I would expect to return information is not performing as expected.

When I run `EXEC sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture` no values are returned. However, I know there my table has CDC enabled from running `SELECT [name], is_tracked_by_cdc FROM sys.tables order by [name]`
and I do have select access to the tables that have CDC enabled.

I tried to run the more granular

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture @source_schema='dbo', @source_name='SUMMARY_CHANGELOG'
```

but the following error appears:

```
Msg 22981, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture, Line 51 [Batch Start Line 0]
Object does not exist or access is denied.
```

If I run `select * from dbo.SUMMARY_CHANGELOG`, I can see the results I expect.

It seems I have proper access to the table, and proper access to the stored procedure, but the data being returned as well as the messages being displayed are telling me something is amiss. Beyond verifying the existence of the table and its having CDC enabled, and my access allowing for querying this information, what else could I look at to correct this issue?

Comment: "Callers must have SELECT permission on **all of the captured columns** of the capture instance and also membership in **any defined gating roles** for the table information to be included" Do you satisfy that?

Comment: I'm not sure - how can I check that? I'm not seeing an error message that would indicate I don't have those rights when I select from the source table or the capture table.

Comment: "Members of the `db_owner` database role can view information about all defined capture instances." I suppose you could also run it as `sa` to view the info. Bit of a catch-22, I know

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out the user ID needed to have `CDC_Role` to view the results of the stored procedure.

Comment: Hi Timbuck, can you please share how you setup this CDC_Role?

Comment: Hi Syed - I don't recall the details. I believe in this case I asked the person responsible for the database to give the user the ```CDC_Role```.